Vuejs + capacitor blank page android
I have build my project and i see my capacitor config is right, but when run on android i get a blank page.


I tried to open index.html by path on chrome but i got same blank page, the console output is like this:

i have search a lot but i still get stuck :(
thanks for answer
I want to success build my vue apps to android using capacitor

How opening an index.html is relevant? I have no experience with this. Meanwhile, if you need to do that and it's a good way, you need to fix the 2 errors: have a running server and fix the CORS issue. Plenty of info on the Internet about that one.

i opening index.html because capacitor used it to build android app, i think i can get some information from that. I also have search about CORS issue but it doesnt help me, when i try to run on server its working cleary but i still get blank page on android

For testing in the browser don’t open the index.html file directly, use some server to run the app, if using vue you probably have a dev server installed already, check your package.json file and see if you have some script for that.

I have already get the problem, my java sdk is out of date. I know it from running gradle on terminal
